# City in which Norwegian Santa lives

Tags: where-on-earth, norway, cities

I'm no expert in Scandinavian languages (Norwegian and such) but I've been wondering where actually does their Santa (Julenissen) live (city)? I've been able to find ambiguous answers on this matter over the Internet in English language that mentioned cities like Oslo, Bergen, Drobak, Svalen and Trondheim. Maybe someone can deliver me with proper information? That would give me some clue on planning my trip.

Comment: The other question says Drøbak, though this is uncited.

Answer (score 2):

According to Norwegian myth, Santa Claus lives on the North Pole. I am not aware of any references in Norwegian fiction to Santa Claus living in a specific city, either in Norway or other countries, although the [Wikipedia article](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julenissen#Julenissen_i_Norge) mentions both Drøbak and Longyearbyen.

I'm Norwegian, if that's a good enough source :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, according to traditional Norwegian myths, Santa Claus lives on the North Pole, as l0b0 says in his answer. However, in many parts of the world, if you *do* send a letter addressed to:

```
Santa Claus 
The North Pole
```

It will end up in Drøbak, where Santa will answer every single letter (note, in many countries (for instance the US) they send it elsewhere). According to the [official tourist information website](http://www.visitdrobak.no/en/activities/santa-claus-live-in-drobak) of Drøbak, this is where Santa lives.

Some, that have figured out the Santa doesn't live on the North Pole, (and neither in Drøbak), knows that the *true* Santa actually resides in [Finland](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Santa_Claus_Village).

However, I think l0b0 is correct in that there's no common "tales" where Santa lives any other place than the North Pole.

This is what I remember from when I was a little kid, and from little kids today.

> I'm Norwegian, if that's a good enough source :)